# Google Maps Javascript API Usage not showing

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I recently (like 4 hours ago) added an api key and enabled billing for Google Cloud Platform so my Google Maps Javascript API wouldn't get blocked at 25,000 places autocomplete requests.   I expected to see usage statistics in Google Cloud Platform immediately but still it shows zero usage activity.   Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are checking the wrong API.

[image]

Try going to Google Places API Web Service : Key features include autocomplete, search, place picker, photos and add place

[image]

OR

Google Maps JavaScript API: build and style a map onto your website.

[image]

Check the usage statistic of these two API to see the request related to place autocomplete. Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks Mr.Rebot - i'm definitely using Google Maps Javascript API and i'm still not seeing any usage yet.